# Running Spring Batch test, doesn't initialize database

Tags: spring-batch, integration-testing

Trying to create some end-to-end tests for an spring batch application, which works great. I get an sql error because it is not initializing Spring Batch processing tables: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "batch_job_instance" does not exist`

I have this code in the `src/test/resources/application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgresql

spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

Which is the same I have on `src/main/resources/application.properties and works.

This is the code I have for `ApplicationTest`:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={
        TestConfiguration.class,
        JobCompletionNotificationListener.class,
        BatchConfiguration.class
})
@SpringBatchTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;


    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
    }
}
```

I have an specific `TestConfiguration` to generate a `Bean` with the `DataSource`.

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassname"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;

    }
```

I was expecting all tables to be created (internal Batch tables and the tables defined in `schema-all.sql`).

But I get the following error `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "batch_job_instance" does not exist`.

I don't understand why in the main application all works automagically, and it doesn't in the test.

Comment: Have you tried to add [@SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) on your test?

Comment: I just tried, and I get same error.

Comment: Since you created the datasource yourself in `TestConfiguration`, it will not be populated automatically. I would remove this data source bean definition and let Spring Boot do it in the test (just like in production code).

Comment: After removing the `TestConfiguration` I get the following error: `No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available`. I had added `TestConfiguration` because the `@Autowired` `DataSource` required in my steps wasn't being created by Spring during tests... I don't know if I'm missing something that causes this `DataSource` not to be created.

Answer (score 1):

If a Spring test misses misses the `BatchDataSourceInitializer` that is being auto-configured by Spring Boot in the actual application, and you don't want to write a full `@SpringBootTest`, you can selectively add the auto-configuration for Spring Batch by adding the annotation

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration(BatchAutoConfiguration.class)
```

This will then provide the initializer for the injected `DataSource`.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, it solved my problem! thank you.